# Using BackgroundWorker to fetch data

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I used the data sources tab to drag and drop some fields from my database onto a form.  This created the reqired textboxes/fields/designer components and also created a fill command by default, which is expected.

On my form load event, the following command takes place:

```
  Me.TblQueueTableAdapter.dt_FillIncompleteCases(Me.BE_DataSet.tblQueue)
```

This command can take a while to fill on the end user's PC.  I would like to display something in the meantime while the data is being retrieved so I added a new borderless form which will show before the fill event, then hide after completion.

So the problem as it stands is the main thread is being blocked due to the database fill code above, and my main thread will not display the borderless form.  The process of showing and hiding works, but because the thread is blocked, the content of the borderless form is blank.  I need to stop the main thread from blocking.

I know I can probably use a background worker to get this data out of the database.  I could instantiate a new table adapter and use the fill command in the do work event.  If I do this, I canpass back the datatable through `e.result` but I dont know how to set the datatable to my designer controls.  How do I do this?

In the run worker completed event, I imagined something like:

```
 Me.BE_DataSet.tblQueueDataTable = e.result
```

But this is a type and cannot be set in this way.  What do I need to do?

Comment: Using the design view is fine for more or less simplistic situations; but when things become complex, you have usually to do everything at runtime. I personally never use the design-view features to communicate with datasources. Just perform the whole connection to the database from the code (e.g., function called on Form Load or, in your case, from the DoWork Event from the BGW, which is started on Form Load). It is pretty easy just do some quick research.

Comment: There's a learning curve here, the one that the designer tried to shortcut for you.  I kinda doubt you'll reach the end of that curve today, there are many places beyond SO that covers the material.  Consider calling the borderless form's Update() method after calling Show() so you can see it.